# Get SelectList Value Via JQUERY on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a `<select>` list that is dynamically populated on page load via AJAX. I am trying to find out the value of the initial selection when the page is loaded AND before a user actually selects something other than the default selection.

After I get the value, I am trying to pass it to a custom function named `PopulateCustomerAlertDIV()`. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
 <cfselect name="company_name" id="company_name" tabindex="0" 
      onchange="PopulateCustomerAlertDIV();" >
      <option>#customers.company_name#</option>
 </cfselect>
```

**Javascript (Populate List)**

```
<!--- Retrieves list of customers --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {       
    //populate the vehicle select list
    $.ajax({
       url: 'cfcs/get_customers.cfc?method=getData&returnformat=json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
           console.log('Success');
           $.each(response.DATA, function(i, row){
            // get value in first column ie "description"
            var company_name = row[0];

            // append new option to list
            $("##company_name").append($('<option/>', { 
                    value: company_name,
                    text : company_name 
            }));

        });
       },
       error: function(msg){
           console.log(msg);
       }
    })
    populateSalesTax();
    console.log('Sales Tax Function Ran from Customer Query Function');
});
</script>
```

**Javascript (Populate DIV):**

```
<script>
function PopulateCustomerAlertDIV(){
    // Populate the customer alert DIV based on the customer selection
    console.log( $("##company_name2>option:selected").attr("Value") );

    $.ajax({
        url:'cfcs/customerAlertDIV.cfc?method=getAlert&returnformat=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { company_name: $("##company_name>option:selected").attr("Value") },
        success: function(obj) {
            JSON.stringify(obj);//to string
            console.log(obj.alert);
            $("##CustomerAlertDIV").html( '<div style="width:80%" align="center"> <br /> <br />' + obj.alert + ' <br /> <br /> </div>' );
                if(obj.alert_priority == 'high' ) {
                    $('##CustomerAlertDIV').removeClass().addClass('alert_error');
                } 
                else if (obj.alert_priority == 'medium' ){
                    $('##CustomerAlertDIV').removeClass().addClass('alert_warning');
                }
                else if(obj.alert_priority == 'low' ){
                    $('##CustomerAlertDIV').removeClass().addClass('alert_info');
                }

            },
        error: function(req, err){ 
                $("##CustomerAlertDIV").html("");
                $('##CustomerAlertDIV').removeClass().addClass('');
                console.log('error'); }
      });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('My Var: ' + x);
    PopulateCustomerAlertDIV();
    console.log('Customer DIV Function Ran');
    populateSalesTax();
    console.log('Sales Tax Function Ran from Document Ready');
});
</script>
```

**Get_Customers.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="query">
        <!---Get Customers --->
        <cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
        select company_name
        from customer_table
        order by company_name ASC
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Return results --->
        <cfreturn data>
    </cffunction>

    <!---Get Customer Sales Tax Info --->
    <cffunction name="getSalesTax" access="remote" returntype="query">
        <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

        <!--- localize function variables --->
        <cfset var dataDetail = "">
        <cfoutput>
        <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
            SELECT tax_rate
            FROM   customer_table
            <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
            WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        </cfquery>
        </cfoutput>

        <cfreturn getSalesTax.tax_rate>
    </cffunction>  
</cfcomponent>
```

**CustomerAlertDIV.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="getAlert" access="remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

        <!--- localize function variables --->
        <cfset var dataDetail = "">

        <cfquery name="getID" datasource="#datasource#" >
            select  customer_id
            from    customer_table
            where   company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#" 
                                    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        </cfquery> 
        <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
            SELECT  ID, alert, alert_priority
            FROM    customer_alerts
            WHERE   customer_id = <cfqueryparam value="#getID.customer_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> AND alert_status = 'on'
        </cfquery>

        <cfoutput query="dataDetail">
            <cfset obj = {
                "alert" = alert,
                "alert_priority" = alert_priority               
             } />

        <cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes"> 
            <cfoutput>
                #serializeJSON(obj)#
            </cfoutput>
        </cfprocessingdirective>
        </cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Whay your selector have multiple #. Suppose to be single hash like this  $('#company_name').val();

Comment: Becuase it is nested inside a CFOUTPUT tag. If I don't put double ## than ColdFusion thinks I didn't define a variable correctly.

Comment: But in jQuery, those selector is false. Try using native javascript like document.getElementById("company_name").value to get the value, then the rest of code using jquery. Have a try first.

Comment: Console Output: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: var x = $('#company_name').val();
Use like this

Comment: Have you ever tried to put var x = $('#company_name').val();
console.log('My Var: ' + x); inside document ready with single #.

Comment: Still same thing: My Var: undefined. My selectlist is being populated dynamically via ColdFusion query. Could it be that even though there are options in the list, javascript can't see them yet cause Im not adding them with the <option> tag?

Comment: Yes I recieve a coldfusion error. Coldfusion var's are specified like #variable#. So a single # in a cfoutput tag throws an error. ## escapes out of that.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - The problem may be mixing events from two different javascript libraries: ExtJS ( used by `cfselect` ) and jQuery. They do not always play well together.  The select list's "load" event is not the same as document.ready. It is possible the select list has not finished loading yet when you try and access it from jQuery.  Generally, you are better off using one library or the other, but not both.

Comment: ok I see. What is the best way to do this then? My main function is initially called with an onChange event on my selectlist. But obviosly that doesn't fire until a change is actually made. But when the page initially loads, there is a valid selection in the selectlist already (from my query), but my function hasn't been told to run yet. Hence my dilema. So my though was to use something like the above code to force the function to fire after page load.

Comment: Well, actually it looks like you are trying to access the select list it *outside* document.ready.  So this line `var x = $('##company_name').val();` may be firing before any DOM elements are loaded, which could be causing the undefined error.  You can try and call the *function* inside `document.ready()`. Might work, but ... again mixing events is not a great idea IMO. You are better off using jQuery to populate the list. Then all elements would be using the same event model.

Comment: You're right, duh. I moved var x = $('##company_name').val(); inside document.ready() and now it is firing correctly. But the console output shows: My Var: ---Make A Selection--- becuase that is my <option> value. However the list is populated with query data. If I remove the <option> tag the console output is My Var; null. How can I handle this?

Comment: (Edit) Umm.. what were you expecting the value to be at that point? :) I do not use `cfselect` much, but I do not think it allows you to select anything by default when using binds. So it makes sense you would only see the default browser behavior (ie select first element).

Comment: I just want to see the first value in my select list which is the first company returned from my query bind. My function expects a company name to be passed to it which it doesn't have until my onchange event is fired. Maybe if I populate the <option> value with the same query results it could fudge this a little?? I don't think the browser would show those reuslts anyways and it would give a the browser real data to pass to my function. Just a thought.

Comment: ok. That actually works. I updated my original question with my edits. Now my colsole.log shows: My Var: All About Care, LLC which is my first company in my list. But........ My custom function doesn't seem to be firing becuase my div is not being updated with that company's data. Am I passing the selectlist value correctly?

Comment: What is PopulateCustomerAlertDIV doing? You only posted an empty function above.  Keep in mind you are still using two different event models, so it may not work consistently every time. I would still recommend using jQuery across the board.

Comment: I updated my question. It is from a question I asked earlier today. It populates a DIV based on my selectlist selection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72381/discussion-between-leigh-and-brian-fleishman).

Comment: No form of javascript is required to get the value.  Something in your coldfusion code is either doing so, or can do so very easily.  You can then make that value available to javascript with a toScript function or cfwddx tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summary from chat)

**Short answer:**

Just to clarify the original issue: it was caused by a timing problem. The code uses several ajax calls, which are *asynchronous*. As a result, the function that refreshes the DIV was trying to grab the selected company *before* the company list was even populated. Obviously, the solution is to wait until after it is populated. Then refresh the DIV.

**Longer answer:**

The original code used a `<cfselect bind...>`, or ExtJS, using a different event model than jQuery. JQuery's `document.ready` event was actually firing before ExtJS loaded the select list. Consequently, when `PopulateCustomerAlertDIV()` tries to grabs the "selected" company:

> ```
>    $.ajax({
>         url:'cfcs/customerAlertDIV.cfc?method=getAlert&returnformat=json',
>         data: { company_name: $("##company_name>option:selected").attr("Value") },
>         .. 
>    });
> ```

... the result is null/undefined. So it does not actually pass a valid company_name to the CFC. That is why the `<div>` is not populated correctly.

> ```
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>    //...
>    // 1st: $.ajax() call to populate select list
>    PopulateList();
>    // 2nd: populate div with selected company
>    PopulateCustomerAlertDIV();
>    //...
> });
> </script>
> ```

The later code uses jQuery to populate the list instead of a "bind". That is better IMO, because it does not mix event models. However, it still has a slight timing problem.

The first function uses an `$.ajax()` call to populate the company list. `$.ajax()` calls are asynchronous by default. Even though the `PopulateCustomerAlertDIV()` function is invoked second, there is no guarantee the first function will have finished executing when it starts. So ultimately, `PopulateCustomerAlertDIV()` is still trying to access the selected company before the company list is even populated.

The solution is to invoke `PopulateCustomerAlertDIV()` after the company list is populated: as Mike suggested, inside the `success()` method of the ajax call. (Though no need to modify the function parameters).

Keep in mind you could also solve the problem by using a synchronous ajax call instead OR forgo ajax altogether and populate the list with a basic cfoutput loop. Then timing would not be an issue. However, those options have different pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but I am still a little short on points for commenting, so putting my comment here. There are two ways I see that would make this easier.Both options require making this change in PopulateCustomerAlertDIV().

```
    // Change to accept passed var
    function PopulateCustomerAlertDIV(selected){
            // Populate the customer alert DIV based on the customer selection

            $.ajax({
                url:'cfcs/customerAlertDIV.cfc?method=getAlert&returnformat=json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { company_name: selected }, // Change to use passed var
```

Option one would be to populate the select list with JS instead of CF. Get the list with an AJAX call. The success function would look something like this:

```
var sel = $('#company_name');
$.each(obj, function(i,j){
    sel.append($('<option>').attr('value', j.Id).text(j.Name));
});
PopulateCustomerAlertDIV(obj[1].company_name);
```

With the html like this:

```
<select name="company_name" id="company_name" onchange="PopulateCustomerAlertDIV(this.value);" />
```

So now the select is populated, and PopulateCustomerAlertDIV() is called for the first time.

Option two would be to pass the value to a function. Calling onload from the body tag allows you to pass a cf var to JS, and seems to be more dependable for this than document ready.

```
<body onload="PopulateCustomerAlertDIV(#customers[1].company_name#)">
```

Whichever way you go, I recommend not using cfinput.

Edit: Premature Submission.

Comment: (Edit) *populate the select list with JS instead of CF* I get what you mean, but technically it is being populated with javascript already, which seems to be the problem. You need to wait until the list is fully loaded, but since the bind uses ExtJS,. its load event is not the same as jQuery's document.ready. (Trying to coordinate the two event models might not be 100% reliable.) IMO the simpler option is to either a) Use jQuery for everything, similar to what you suggested above OR b) just populate a <select> list the old fashioned way, via cfoutput loop. Then event timing is not an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You could always do it the easy way.  I just ran this code:

```
<cfset abc = "hello">
<cfoutput>
<script>
alert("#abc#");
</script>
```

and got my alert.  That means you can do this.

```
<cfif you have the selected value identified>
<cfset javascriptVar = that value>
<cfelse>
<cfset javascriptVar = the first value that will appear in your select>
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
<script>
var varFromColdFusion = #javascriptVar#;
etc
</script>
```

Comment: (Edit) That seems a bit convoluted. Why bother creating a javascript variable at all? If you are going to run the query on the form page, instead of using a bind, it is simpler to populate the list with a plain query loop. Then you do not need any extra javascript variables.

Comment: @Leigh - I redid it using AJAX to populate the list.  My original post is updated with the edits. I'm still seeing the same behavior though. Doesn't seem to be grabbing the select list value.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - You forgot to call the function after loading the select list :)  Invoke it at the end of `success` and it works fine.

Comment: Not sure if it is a copy paste error, but you have the `$(document).ready...` event listed twice. It should only be listed once.

Comment: Where shoul it go? Right before the error? And I should insert PopulateCustomerAlertDIV();  ?